# Django request.POST.items() not behaving as expected

Tags: django

I have an incoming ajax request, if I print post that like this:

```
print("post_data %s" % request.POST)
```

I get this:

```
post_data <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...'], 'contact_method 1[]': ['Facebook', 'https://www.facebook.com/aandro.veinilla/', 'Send me a message'], 'contact_method 2[]': ['Whatsapp', '+593998375445', 'contact me after 8pm']}>
```

As you can see, it is a dict with some keys and the values are lists. But if I print it like this:

```
    for k, v in request.POST.items():
        print("k: %s" % k)
        print("v: %s" % v)
```

I get this:

```
k: csrfmiddlewaretoken
v: ...hEm9OcUE
k: contact_method 1[]
v: Send me a message
k: contact_method 2[]
v: contact me after 8pm
```

It only prints the last item in each list, why? I need to iterate over the all the values received, not only the last item in the list.

**Also**
One weird thing that might have something to do (not sure) is that django appends '[]' to the dictionary keys. I'm sure I didn't do that in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`QueryDict.items(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.items) only return the *last value*. Proabably, you should use [**`QueryDict.lists(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists)

```
for k, v in request.POST.lists():
    print("k: %s" % k)
    print("v: %s" % v)
```

Note that, this will return a list even there is only a single item in the `request.POST`

Comment: This solved it. However, I still think `.items()` has an inadequate behavior.